# Order of adjectives in "free weekly two-hour scientific meetings"

Tags: grammar

What is the correct order of these four adjectives in the phrase "free weekly two-hour scientific meetings"? I'm not exactly sure where to put 'two-hour'.

Comment: Looks fine as it is to me.

Comment: personally, I'd put "free weekly scientific meetings, Mondays 10:00-12:00", or some other phrasing depending on the context.